# How can i get back the unique Id of any file at Alfresco?

Tags: java, alfresco

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzRzU.png)

I'm currently developing a java / JEE application. The attachement will be stored in alfresco.

I want to create a folder and within each folder subfolders.
I managed to create the parent folder:

```
CreateFolder (u String, String p, String floderName, String uuid,
   FolderDescription String, String foldertitle, String alfrescoTicket)
```

PS: I retrieve the UUID(unique Id at alfresco) manually. (This is not a problem for the parent folder).

But when I want to create a `sub_folder`  that is under the parent folder (I don't have the uuid of parent folder).

I want to find a solution to recuperate file's uuid when it is created.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you work with `CMIS` ?!?

Comment: Thank you for making time to respond.
I don't think I'm using CMIS (I'm actually a beginner at alfresco )/

Comment: to make the things that you want to make ( alfresco id, create folder, and many other features) you want to make it in Java ?!?

Comment: I'm working in JEE.

Comment: you have the choose between two solutions `CMIS` or `Rest API` did you know that or should i right an answer giving more details ?!?

Comment: yeah actually i've been working with REST api .

Comment: did you see https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-5510-repository-restful-api-reference#w_retrieveparentfolder28getfolderparent29

Answer (score 2):

You should get the `nodeId` (unique id in `workspace://SpacesStore`) as JSON response:

```
{
  "nodeRef": "workspace://SpacesStore/{nodeId}"
}
```

Consider to use the following API:

---

### Alfresco 5.2 (Early Access) [Rest API](http://docs.alfresco.com/community/concepts/alfresco-sdk-tutorials-using-rest-api-explorer.html)

Create a node and add it as a primary child of node `parentNodeId`:

```
POST /alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/nodes/{parentNodeId}/children

{
  "name":"My new sub-folder",
  "nodeType":"cm:folder"
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "entry": {
    /* ... */
    "name": "My new sub-folder",
    "id": {nodeId},
    "nodeType": "cm:folder"
  }
}
```

---

### [Apache Chemistry OpenCMIS](https://chemistry.apache.org/java/opencmis.html) - a CMIS library for Java

- [create a session and connect to a repository](https://chemistry.apache.org/java/examples/example-create-session.html)

  ```
  Session session = factory.createSession(sessionParams);
  ```
- [get a parent folder](https://chemistry.apache.org/java/examples/example-list-folder.html)

  ```
  CmisObject po = session.getObject(session.createObjectId(parentNodeId));
  Folder pf = (Folder) po;
  ```
- [create a new folder](https://chemistry.apache.org/java/examples/example-create-update.html)

  ```
  Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  properties.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, "cmis:folder");
  properties.put(PropertyIds.NAME, "My new sub-folder");
  Folder newFolder = pf.createFolder(properties);
  ```